# How to display credit cards logo based on their first or two first numbers

Tags: angular, attributes

I am a beginner to Angular and trying to display the logo of five credit cards based on their first digit or the two first digit using attribute directive. The code is below, it works for Visa and mastercard, and for the first two digit if there is not '4' or '5' digits in them, if there is it changes to visa or mastercrd. For example number '34' instead of displaying Amex logo displays visa or '65' for discover shows mastercard. In addition, it works just for the first string, '38' for diners shows nothing.

I appreciate any help!

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[appCCImage]'
})
export class CCImageDirective implements OnChanges {

    constructor() { }
    @Input() cardNumber: string;
    @HostBinding('src') imageSource;
    ngOnChanges() {
        this.imageSource = './assets/default.png';
        if(this.cardNumber){
            if (this.cardNumber.indexOf('30' || '36' || '38' || '39') >-1) 
                this.imageSource = './assets/diners.png';
            if (this.cardNumber.indexOf('5') >-1)  
                this.imageSource = './assets/mastercard.png';
            if (this.cardNumber.indexOf('34' || '37') >-1)
                this.imageSource = './assets/amex.png';
            if (this.cardNumber.indexOf('60' || '64' || '65') >-1)
                this.imageSource = './assets/discover.png';
            if (this.cardNumber.indexOf('4') >-1)
                this.imageSource = "./assets/visa.png"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please check my updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following function, modify the response as per your need or retrun from the function, I have used this and works fine. So I take out 4 values and then run a if else check for the value. This was a watch function in Vuejs (don't know what will be the equivalent in Angular, but onKeyPress will work considering basic html events)

```
cardNumber(value) {
  if (value != "") {

    // Taking out values from the input
    var oneValue = parseInt(value.substring(0, 1));
    var twoValue = parseInt(value.substring(0, 2));
    var threeValue = parseInt(value.substring(0, 3));
    var fourValue = parseInt(value.substring(0, 4));

    //the if else
    if (twoValue == 34 || twoValue == 37) {
      //card is amex
      this.cardType = "fa-cc-amex";
    } else if (oneValue == 4) {
      //card is visa
      this.cardType = "fa-cc-visa";
    } else if (
      (threeValue >= 300 && threeValue <= 305) || fourValue == 3095 ||
      twoValue == 36 || twoValue == 38 || twoValue == 39) {
      //card is diners club or could be diners club
      this.cardType = "fa-cc-diners-club";
    } else if ((fourValue >= 2221 && fourValue <= 2720) ||
      (twoValue >= 51 && twoValue <= 55)) {
      //card is mastercard
      this.cardType = "fa-cc-mastercard";
    } else if (fourValue >= 3528 && fourValue <= 3589) {
      //card is jcb
      this.cardType = "fa-cc-jcb";
    } else if (fourValue == 6011) {
      //card is discover
      this.cardType = "fa-cc-discover";
    } else {
      //unknown card
      this.cardType = "";
    }
  } else {
    //unknown card
    this.cardType = "";
  }
}
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. This is a part of a small team project that I have to use attribute directive of Angular. I do not know what to use to consider two digit together as a value for a specific card. and how can I use more than one value for indexOf? I am using logical or (||) but it is not working.

Comment: Well you can try my code once. So my approach just takes the input and splits it into four inputs and then performs the if_else. The indexOf checks for the provided string in whole input not just the starting letters and that is why your code is failing. The logical or operator is working fine. https://codepen.io/kuldeept010/pen/yLJNvop i just checked your code here.